# "Can be used only in preamble" when using the "import" package

Tags: errors, import

My code, which is actually supposed to work according to import's [official readme](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/import/import.pdf) if I understand it correctly:

`./main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}

\import{FirstChapter/}{main}

\end{document}
```

`FirstChapter/main.tex`:

```
Test
```

I get the following errors:

```
Line 1: Can be used only in preamble. \documentclass
Line 2: Can be used only in preamble. \usepackage
Line 4: Can be used only in preamble. \begin{document}
Line 1: Can be used only in preamble. \documentclass
Line 2: Can be used only in preamble. \usepackage
Line 4: Can be used only in preamble. \begin{document}

... (always the same pattern: lines 1, 2, 4)


Line 6: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [text input levels=50] \import{FirstChapter/}{main}
```

I think LaTeX tries to include `./main.tex` over and over again. Is that right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is due to both files having the same name.  The normal version of `\import` uses `TEXINPUTS` to look for files, and when two files with the same name are in the search path, it is likely to choose the one from the current/working directory.  Using the starred form, `\import*`, will prevent searching the `TEXINPUTS` path.

Thus, the solution in this case is to (1) either rename the imported file so it has a different name from the main file (i.e., `main.tex`), or (2) use:

```
\import*{FirstChapter/}{main}
```

(And of course these two solutions can be combined: there is a danger that filenames as generic as `main.tex` might crop up in unexpected places.  Renaming and disabling `TEXINPUTS` searching might both be good ideas.)